# how to sort json array with dates in descending order with php

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I the folder `data` i store json files which look like this:

```
{
    "date": "2021-08-05",
    "time": "13:00",
    "name": "John"
}
```

To loop through all the json files:

```
$files = glob('data/*.json'); // all json files in data dir
foreach($files as $file) {
   $objs = json_decode(file_get_contents($file)); // all json objects in array
   echo $objs->date.'<br />';
}
```

Output above gives me all dates but in ascending order. How can i output them in descending order? (oldest date first)

Comment: Put all the data into a single array and then sort it, before outputting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way with pushing all the individual array's to a single array and the use `array_multisort` like below to sort by **date** field,

```
$files = glob('data/*.json'); // all json files in data dir
foreach($files as $file) {
   $main[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),1); // push individual array
}
array_multisort(array_column($main, 'date'), SORT_DESC, $main);
print_r($main);
```

Comment: Ok. But how does my foreach now look like to create the output?

Comment: The same way I added above, it just uses the foreach and pushes the individual `$file` as an array to the new array `$main`. Some kind of demo for clarity: https://rextester.com/FMBBVR78628